# How can I call commoly used functions in slim 3 framework?

Tags: php, slim, slim-3

I am building my website in Slim 3 MVC framework.I need to call some commonly used functions for controller (Eg: For Alias of page title I am using a function called `function getAlias(){.....}`).

Where I have to create those functions? How can I call inside controllers?

Answer (score 0):

There's a number of ways to do this. If the functions have no side effects, then one option would be to have a utilities class with static methods in it it.

Another option would be to extend all your route actions from a common class and use that:

```
// CommonAction.php
class CommonAction
{
    protected function getAlias() { }
}

// HomeAction.php
class HomeAction extends CommonAction
{
    public function __construct(/*dependencies here*/) { }

    public function __invoke($request, $response, $args) {
        // route action code here
        return $response;
    }
}

// index.php
$app = new Slim\App(require('settings.php'));

$container = $app->getContainer();
$container[HomeAction::class] = function ($c) {
    return new HomeAction(/*dependencies*/);
}

$app->get('/', HomeAction::class);

$app->run();
```

If the functionality is part of your domain layer, then inject those classes into your route actions as a dependency.